# Tutorial - Create news items. Getting 404 after submitting a new article

Tags: php, codeigniter

Getting to know **Code Igniter**, and was following this particular section of the tutorial:

`http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/create_news_items.html`

Everything works until I click *"Create news item"*. I receive **404** page and my URL bar looks like this:

`http://localhost/tut/index.php/news/localhost/tut/index.php/news/create`

Thinking maybe it's route's fault:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "news/index";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['news/(:any)'] = 'news/view/$1';
$route['news'] = 'news'; // what's this for?
$route['news/create'] = 'news/create';
```

Also, my config.php:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'localhost/tut';
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this thead](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/209923/), you have your `base_url` set incorrectly. Please follow advice as per thread.

Comment: Which one? Create.php? They are exaclty the same as the tutorial's.

Comment: It's still your `base_url`, you need the http in it, as the thread says. AND you need to end it with a trailing slash as the CI docs say. So: `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/tut/';`